# Как установить datasource плагин в графну

Tags: grafana

Пишу плагин типа datasource для grafana. Создаю стандартный плагин с помощью команды

```
npx @grafana/create-plugin@latest
```

Далее делаю билд и как указано в оффициальной документации кладу в папку к остальным плагинам.
Перезагружаю grafan-у, но ничего никуда не добовляется.
Пробывал в файл GrafanaLabs\grafana\conf\provisioning\datasources\datasources.yml прописать

```
apiVersion: 1

datasources:
- name: First plugin
  type: ni-firstplugin-datasource
  access: direct
  url: /
  version: 1
```

Плагин добовляется в список, но неработает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите что делаю не так? В офф документации все так просто, но ничего не получается.